# Determine if polygon normals, points inside or outside polygon

Tags: java, linear-algebra

Whats the proper way to determine if normal points of polygon point inside or outside polygon? I have a list of Lines (p1, p2, normalVec) in correct order. I think I should sort them CW or CCW and then somehow calculate normal Vector with direction Vector of my line.[image]

Left one should return Outside and the right one Inside.

Comment: Okay and did you try doing what you explained above?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm doing this exact thing right now with my game engine.
What I do to determine which way a polygon is facing is to always wind the triangles the same way. For me, I always wind them clockwise.
Then using those triangles, calculate the normal vector. Here's my code for it:

```
public static Point GetNormalVector(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
{
    double diff_x = p3.GetExX() - p2.GetExX();
    double diff_y = p3.GetExY() - p2.GetExY();
    double diff_z = p3.GetExZ() - p2.GetExZ();
    double diff_x1 = p1.GetExX() - p2.GetExX();
    double diff_y1 = p1.GetExY() - p2.GetExY();
    double diff_z1 = p1.GetExZ() - p2.GetExZ();
    Point orig = new Point(0, 0, 0);
    orig.SetX((diff_y * diff_z1) - (diff_y1 * diff_z));
    orig.SetY((diff_z * diff_x1) - (diff_z1 * diff_x));
    orig.SetZ((diff_x * diff_y1) - (diff_x1 * diff_y));
    NormalizeVector(orig);
    return orig;
}
```

Now we have the normal vector of the polygon.
Depending on which way you wind your triangles, the normal vectors will always point the same way--in or out.
You will know which way they point when you calculate the normal vector. For me, clockwise = out, counterclockwise = in.

Does this answer your question?